# Redirect file in linux using length

Tags: linux, shell, unix, substring

Am trying to redirect the file based on the length.
I have a file having the value, **I like Linux**
I have to create a new file base on length, 0-6 will provide me **I like**.

In case of line number we can redirect using,

```
head-100 file_name.txt > file_name_new.txt
```

Not sure how to redirect using length of the data.
Any suggestion will be helpful

Comment: You could use [GNU sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/) or write [in C](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c) the program doing what you want. BTW, I don't understand your question. See [syscalls(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) like [stat(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html)

Comment: `cut -b 1-6 file_name.txt`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you say "length of data", do you mean number of characters of each line? If so you can use `cut` command:

```
head -n100 file_name.txt | cut -c 1-10 > file_name_new.txt
```

Where [1-10] is the range of the characters you want to keep.